# How to filters by category using redux-toolkit in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

How to implement filter by category in shopping cart projects in redux-toolkit in ReactJS projects. I tried in my filterSlice.js file but I am not getting means data is not filtering by categories. Kindly help me, what should I implement in my code for the product categories filter in my projects. I want only filters in categories like (laptops, smartphones, home decoration, etc) by using redux-toolkit.

Home.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Products, SearchBar } from "../components";
import Filters from "../components/Filters";
import { fetchProducts, handleSearchProducts, STATUSES } from "../redux/features/productSlice";
import { FaFilter } from "react-icons/fa";
import SidebarFilterPanel from "../components/SidebarFilterPanel";
import { setCategoryFilter } from "../redux/features/filterSlice";
const categories = [
  "Smartphones",
  "Laptops",
  "Fragrances",
  "Skincare",
  "Groceries",
  "Home-Decoration",
];
const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { products, status } = useSelector((state) => state.product.products);
  const { price, rating, discount, category } = useSelector(state => state.filters)

console.log(products);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("")
  const [openFilter, setOpenFilter] = useState(false);
  const openFilterPanel = () => setOpenFilter(!openFilter);



  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts())
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Shoping Website";
  }, []);

  const searchProducts = products?.filter(product => {
    if(!searchTerm.length) return product
    if(!product.title) return
    return product.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  })

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleFilterCategory = (category) => {
    const filterCategory = products?.filter(product => product.category === category)
    dispatch(setCategoryFilter(filterCategory))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex gap-4 justify-between px-4">
        <div className="hidden md:block">
          <Filters categories={categories} handleFilterCategory={handleFilterCategory} />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full">
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <SearchBar handleSearch={handleSearch} />
            <div
              onClick={openFilterPanel}
              className={`bg-black text-white py-[10px] px-3 md:hidden block rounded cursor-pointer ml-2 mt-3 duration-1000 transition-all`}
            >
              <FaFilter onClick={openFilterPanel} />
            </div>

            {openFilter && <SidebarFilterPanel categories={categories} />}
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-4 p-2 items-center justify-center mr-auto ml-auto w-full mt-4">
            {searchProducts &&
              searchProducts
              ?.filter((product) => product.price <= price)
              ?.filter((product => product.rating <= rating))
              ?.filter((product) => product.discountPercentage <= discount)
              ?.map((product) => (
                <Products key={product.id} product={product} />
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

filterSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const filterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "filters",
  initialState: {
    price: 1500,
    rating: 5,
    discount: 20,
    category: []
  },
  reducers: {
    setPriceFilter: (state, action) => {
      state.price = Math.max(0, action.payload);
    },

    setRatingFilter: (state, action) => {
        state.rating = Math.max(0, action.payload)
    },

    setDiscountFilter: (state, action) => {
        state.discount = Math.max(0, action.payload)
    },

    setCategoryFilter: (state, action) => {
        state.category.push(action.payload)
    }
  },
});

export const actions = {
  ...filterSlice.actions,
};

export const { setPriceFilter,  setRatingFilter, setDiscountFilter, setCategoryFilter } = filterSlice.actions

export default filterSlice.reducer;
```

productSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
const baseURL = "https://dummyjson.com/products";
export const STATUSES = Object.freeze({
  IDLE: "idle",
  ERROR: "error",
  LOADING: "loading",
});

export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/fetch",
  async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(baseURL);
    const data = await res.data;
    return data;
  }
);

export const getProduct = createAsyncThunk(
  "product/getProduct",
  async (id, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/${id}`);
      console.log(id);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response);
    }
  }
);




const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "product",
  initialState: {
    products: [],
    product: {},
    status: STATUSES.IDLE,
  },
  reducers: {
   
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchProducts.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = STATUSES.LOADING;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.products = action.payload;
        state.status = STATUSES.IDLE;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = STATUSES.ERROR;
      })
      .addCase(getProduct.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = STATUSES.LOADING;
      })

      .addCase(getProduct.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = STATUSES.IDLE;
        state.product = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { handlePriceFilter, handleSearchProducts } = productSlice.actions;
export default productSlice.reducer;



import React from "react";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setPriceFilter, setRatingFilter, setDiscountFilter, setCategoryFilter } from "../redux/features/filterSlice";
```

Filters

```
const Filters = ({ categories, handleFilterCategory }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const price = useSelector((state) => state.filters.price);
  const rating = useSelector((state) => state.filters.rating);
  const discount = useSelector((state) => state.filters.discount);
  const category = useSelector((state) => state.filters.category);
  console.log(price);
  return (
    <div className=" w-[200px] shadow-lg h-[500px] flex flex-col px-2 py-10">
      <div className="w-[150px] ml-auto mr-auto flex flex-col gap-2">
        <p className="font-bold">Price</p>
        <Slider
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          aria-labelledby="range-slider"
          min={0}
          max={1500}
          value={price}
          onChange={(event, value) => dispatch(setPriceFilter(value))}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="px-2 mt-6">
        <p className="font-bold mb-2">Catogries</p>
        {categories.map((category, index) => (
          <p
            className="cursor-pointer text-sm my-2 hover:text-orange-500"
            key={index}
            onClick={() => handleFilterCategory(category)}
          >
            {category}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="w-[150px] pl-2 flex flex-col gap-2 my-2">
        <p className="font-bold">Discount</p>
        <Slider
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          aria-labelledby="range-slider"
          min={0}
          max={20}
          value={discount}
          onChange={(event, value) => dispatch(setDiscountFilter(value))}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="w-[150px] pl-2 flex flex-col gap-2">
        <p className="font-bold">Rating</p>
        <Slider
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          aria-labelledby="range-slider"
          min={0}
          max={5}
          value={rating}
          onChange={(event, value) => dispatch(setRatingFilter(value))}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filters;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle the category filter in the same way that you are handling the price and ratings filters.  That is:

1. The `Filters` component accesses the current filter from the redux `filters` state.

```
const price = useSelector((state) => state.filters.price);
```

2. The `Filters` component handles changes to the current filter by dispatching an action whose payload is the new value of the filter.

```
onChange={(event, value) => dispatch(setPriceFilter(value))}
```

3. The `filterSlice` responds to that action and updates the redux `filters` state.

```
setPriceFilter: (state, action) => {
  state.price = Math.max(0, action.payload);
},
```

4. The `Products` component accesses the current filter value from the redux `filters` state and the unfiltered list of products from the `product` state.

```
const { products, status } = useSelector((state) => state.product.products);
const { price, rating, discount, category } = useSelector(state => state.filters)
```

5. The `Products` component applies the filter to the array of products before displaying them.

```
?.filter((product) => product.price <= price)
```

(Steps 4 and 5 can also be implemented by using `createSelector` to select the filtered products list)

---

In contrast, what you are doing right now is dispatching an array of filtered products to your redux state, rather than dispatching the value of the filter.

Comment: I have done all of the fitter property but I want the filter property of categories like(smartphones, laptops, home decoration, etc) as mentioned in the Home.js categories array. I want filter property on all categories how to do filter property using redux-toolkit